# Changing Google Analytics transport type to work around redirects

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, content-security-policy

We've implemented a Content Security Policy (CSP) header recently on the website where we restrict sources from which the content can be loaded on the page.

After that we've noticed a curious behaviour of Google Analytics with [display features](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3450482) task enabled. It loads a tracking pixel from `google-analytics.com/r/collect`, then redirect to `doubleclick.net` domain which then redirects to `google.com/ads/ga-audiences` which then redirects further to `google.gTLD/ads/ga-audiences`, where gTLD is Google's geographic top-level domain depending on the user's location. As we didn't put every top-level domain in the CSP header we started to get reports on the CSP violations.

Unfortunately, everything I could find about that was how to disable displayFeaturesTask either in Google Analytics or in the tracking code. But nothing that could disable redirects while keeping the feature.

I have found out myself that by changing the [transport type](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport) to either `xhr` or `beacon` changes tracking behaviour to call `google-analytics.com/r/collect` without further redirects.

My question is what impact does transport type have on tracking performance comparing to default `image` type?